# Possible inconsistency in conversion from text to numeric

Tags: r, type-conversion

Compare the conversion of a character string  with `as.numeric` to how it *can* be done with `read.fwf` .

```
as.numeric("457")  # 457
as.numeric("4 57") # NA with warning message
```

Now read from a file "fwf.txt" containing exactly "  5 7 12 4" .

```
foo<-read.fwf('fwf.txt',widths=c(5,5),colClasses='numeric',header=FALSE)
  V1  V2
1 57 124

foo<-read.fwf('fwf.txt',widths=c(5,5),colClasses='character',header=FALSE)
     V1    V2
1   5 7  12 4
```

Now, I'll note that in the "numeric" version, `read.fwf` does concatenation the same way Fortran does.  I was just a bit surprised that it doesn't throw an error or `NA` in the same manner as `as.numeric` .   Anyone know why?

Comment: `read.fwf` calls `read.table`, which is the function that deals with `colClasses`. You can get the same behavior using `read.table` instead of `read.fwf`. For example, if you change the contents of your file to " 5 7|12 4" and then read it with `read.table("fwf.txt", header=FALSE, sep="|", colClasses="numeric")`, you get the same result. I figured `read.table` must get rid of intervening spaces between digit characters when it knows that the class is supposed to be numeric, but in looking at the function code I couldn't tell for sure whether that's what's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @eipi10 pointed out, the space eliminating behavior is not unique to `read.fwf`. It actually comes form the `scan()` function (which is used by `read.table` which is used by `read.fwf`). Actually the scan() function will remove spaces (or tabs if they are not specified as the delimiter) from any value that is not a character as it process the input stream. Once it has the "cleaned" the value of spaces, then it uses the same function as `as.numeric` to turn that value into a number. With character values it don't take out any white space unless you set `strip.white=TRUE` which will only remove space from the beginning and end of the value.

Observe these examples

```
scan(text="TRU E", what=logical(), sep="x")
# [1] TRUE
scan(text="0 . 0 0 7", what=numeric(), sep="x")
# [1] 0.007
scan(text=" text    ", what=character(), sep="~")
# [1] " text    "
scan(text=" text book   ", what=character(), sep="~", strip.white=T)
# [1] "text book"
scan(text="F\tALS\tE", what=logical(), sep=" ")
# [1] FALSE
```

You can find the source for `scan()` in `/src/main/scan.c` and the specific part responsible for this behavior is [around this line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2da7b84ba592cbf876b3ac3842f59b8b6c07ddf3/src/main/scan.c#L392).

If you wanted `as.numeric` to behave like, you could create a new function like

```
As.Numeric<-function(x) as.numeric(gsub(" ", "", x, fixed=T))
```

in order to get

```
As.Numeric("4 57")
# [1] 457
```